# How do I change my username and profile picture?

Tags: support, display-names, profile-picture, profile-edit

Can anyone please tell me how to change my name and profile picture on Stack Exchange?

Comment: You could not choose worse tags. Amazing

Comment: Sorry. I am not so familiar with this application. Please guide me.

Comment: Already retagged. And to change name and avatar, just go to your profile page then [Edit Profile & Settings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) tab

Comment: I don't see this ending well.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your profile by clicking your avatar in the top bar
2. Go to the Edit Profile & Settings tab
3. ???
4. Profit